# Restarted Visual Studio Code and now my code doesn't work

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

```
print('==', end='', flush=True)
```

the above code give the error "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" even though it was working fine? All the variables seem to have turned white rather than blue (which is what it used to be) in Visual Studio Code

Help please?!

Here is the whole source code (it's for a hangman game): https://www.codepile.net/pile/QmJE5BYO

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the traceback!

Comment: Ditch VS code and use Pycharm

Comment: Syntax errors are usually an unclosed quote or bracket on the previous line.  That could show as a color change in an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to run your code, except for needing to add `alreadyGuessedLetters = []`, it works well.

It has not given me the error message of `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. So could you provide the traceback of it? Such as a screenshot. And have you tried to restart the VSCode again?

I can't see the color of your code, Have you tried to switch the color theme?

You can take the command of `Developer:Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` to check the colorization ruler of the semantic token like this:

[image]

[image]